# Firebase cloud messaging implementation in JSF web app

Tags: web, firebase, jsf-2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried the firebase cloud messaging [Sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) with firebase cli, after that tried to bring the same approach into normal web app with JSF framework, but end with error on service-worker and lot of other issues.So need clarification that FCM can be implemented only through Firebase CLI and firebase or it can be accomate with any application servers like Tomcat, Wildfly.

`browserErrorMessage
:
"Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script."
code
:
"messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message
:
"Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
stack
:
"FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js:525:225"
__proto__
:
Error`